# how can I automate the process of login to my remote host via jump host

Tags: ssh, login, autologin

I am using a Windows machine and I connect to my remote host via a jump host using a SSH software (I use [mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) for now). Now my login process is like this:

1. Load the jump host session I have saved in mobaxterm (I have set up the ip, port, user name and passwd for the jump host)
2. Now I am in the jump host. I am prompted to select a server group. I enter a given number and press `Enter` key.
3. I am prompted again to select a server. I enter another given number and press `Enter` key. Now I am on the remote server **but with another user name**.
4. I use `su - $MYUSERNAME` command to switch account and I am prompted to enter my passwd for the remote host. After entering my passwd and press `Enter` key, I login into my own account in the remote host, finally!

Every time I open a new session in mobaxterm. I have to repeat the above process, which is rather boring and tedious. Are are there better ways in which I can automate this process so I can login into my final account without having to input these info every time?

Comment: If the jump host is giving a menu, you are doing it wrong. Try to use SSH keys

Comment: I do not know details. But the jump host is configured to give you a list and then accept your input. After input the group and server number, you can get to the remote server.

Comment: I use and setup regularly jumphosts. That setup does not seem conducive to try to automate tasks done concurrently in several servers at a time. I would bring that issue with whoever is taking care of it.

Comment: Use GUI ssh clients with expect auto login support,  if you have excess to Linux or CYGWIN , create a expect script to do so

Comment: If step *2.* is a graphical interaction, then perhaps you can use a tool like [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to "click" for you, otherwise mobaxterm says it has a "plugin" with the `expect` command (tcl,...) that typically is used for this sort of login. You might find more existing answers on stackoverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46003940/5008284).

Comment: @meuh, no, all the steps are in the terminal. There is no GUI involved.

Answer (score 0):

i was searching for same issue and find the following link

http://blog.remibergsma.com/2013/05/28/creating-a-multi-hop-ssh-tunnel-by-chaining-ssh-commands-and-using-a-jump-host/

so you would do 
put in the "Remote host" the jumbserver1 and "Specify username" your login username
and in "execute command"

ssh -A -t jumbserver2 \ssh -A -t myserver

Comment: Welcome @AbdoKota thank you for the answer; in order to get better readability please use the proper syntax